# "Module not found error" while trying to call a function that is in another directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, modulenotfounderror

Trying to call a function yamlCreation() which is in another directory into this python file ..
the path of this file is

path:bss_micro_svcs/bss_micro_svcs/kubectl.py

Calling File: "kubectl.py"

```
    from bss_micro_svcs.kubectl_utils.templating_to_yaml import yamlCreation
      class Kube(Svcs):
        def startService(self, cluster_info, service, service_profile):
            yamlCreation()
            
    
    k=Kube()
    k.startService()
```

yamlCreation() function is in this python file named "templating_to_yaml.py"
the path of the file is..
path:bss_micro_svcs/kubectl_utils/templating_to_yaml.py

```
function to be called is inside this file:"templating_to_yaml.py"

 
    file_loader = FileSystemLoader('bss_micro_svcs/bss_micro_svcs/yamls/templates')
    env = Environment(loader=file_loader)


    #deployment.yaml templating
    deployment_template=env.get_template('deployment.tmpl')
    deployment_output=deployment_template.render(deployment_name='nginx-deployment',deployment_app='nginx',deployment_replicas='3',deployment_container_name='nginx',deployment_image='nginx:1.14.2',deployment_container_port=80)


    deployment_outfile=open('bss_micro_svcs/bss_micro_svcs/yamls/services/integration/deployment.yaml','w')
    deployment_outfile.write(deployment_output)
    deployment_outfile.close()


    #*********************************************************************************************************************************************************#

    #service.yaml templating
    service_template=env.get_template('services.tmpl')
    service_output=service_template.render(service_name='integration-service',service_name_space='demo-sandbox',service_app='integration',service_port=8090,target_port=8090)

    service_outfile=open('bss_micro_svcs/bss_micro_svcs/yamls/services/integration/services.yaml','w')
    service_outfile.write(service_output)
    service_outfile.close()
```

GETTING AN ERROR:

```
┌──(bss_micro_svcs-jnO67Li7)(RK㉿kali)-[~/Desktop/servicelaunchmgr]
└─$ /home/RK/.local/share/virtualenvs/bss_micro_svcs-jnO67Li7/bin/python /home/RK/Desktop/servicelaunchmgr/bss_micro_svcs/bss_micro_svcs/kubectl.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/RK/Desktop/servicelaunchmgr/bss_micro_svcs/bss_micro_svcs/kubectl.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bss_micro_svcs.kubectl_utils.templating_to_yaml import yamlCreation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bss_micro_svcs'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set environment variable PYTHONPATH so the interpreter could know where to start looking for the module to import. I would suggest to set it in the root module.

Reference: https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html